# How to find exceptional points?

Tags: energy, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, photonics

I am working using some models described by 2,3 or 4 level system hamiltonians. I want to see if these hamiltonians have any exceptional points. How do I go about it?

For example, I am considering the 1D Su-Schrieffer-Heeger (SSH) model with bulk-momentum hamiltonian

$$H=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & v+we^{ik} \\
v+we^{-ik} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The energies are $$E_{\pm}=\pm\sqrt{v^2+w^2+2vw\cos(k)}$$
How do I proceed from here? One way is to play with the variables $v,w$ and give them random complex values and check if the eigenmodes at the degenerate points are the same. However this is awfully specific. Is there a more general way to go about it?

Comment: What is your definition of 'exceptional points'?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer but you can look to [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7536) for inspiration. The author claims that an exceptional point occurs when the energy has a square-root branch point as a function of a parameter $\lambda$. See equation 4 for an explicit function. This tells you that you must try to find such a square-root branch point as a function of your two complex parameters $v/w$ and $k$.